# Firebase Realtime Database: Query by if list contains value

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to working with Firebase RTDB. I'm working on a school project and need help. I have the following class which is stored in the database.

```java
public class ShopSyncModel {

    private String uid = "";
    private String name = "";
    private String description = "";
    private List<String> userUids = new ArrayList<>();

    public ShopSyncModel() {
    }

    public ShopSyncModel(String uid, String name, String description, List<String> userUids) {
        this.uid = uid;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.userUids = userUids;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("uid", uid);
        result.put("name", name);
        result.put("description", description);
        result.put("userUids", userUids);
        return result;
    }

    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public List<String> getUserUids() {
        return userUids;
    }

    public void setUserUids(List<String> userUids) {
        this.userUids = userUids;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ShopSyncModel{" +
                "uid='" + uid + '\'' +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                ", userUids=" + userUids +
                '}';
    }
}
```

When stored in the database, it looks like this:
[image: Example entry in database]

I'm wanting to fetch all the ShopSyncModel instances where 'userUids' contains the provided userUid.

```java
@Singleton
public class ShopSyncsFirebaseReference {

    private static final String SHOP_SYNCS_COLLECTION = "shop_syncs";
    private static final String USER_UIDS_FIELD = "userUids";

    private final DatabaseReference shopSyncsCollection = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference(SHOP_SYNCS_COLLECTION);

    // other methods removed here for brevity  
 
    public Task<DataSnapshot> getShopSyncsWithUserUid(String userUid) {
        Query query = shopSyncsCollection.orderByChild(USER_UIDS_FIELD).equalTo(userUid);
        return query.get();
    }

}
```

When I run this query, nothing is returned. Is there anything wrong with what I've shared so far? I'm running the query in order to populate a recycler adapter. The log prints that the size of the list is zero.

```java
public class MyShopSyncsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // rest of code omitted for brevity

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_shop_syncs);

        // check if the user is signed in
        FirebaseUser currentUser = checkIfUserIsLoggedInAndFetch(true);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: user signed in with email " + currentUser.getEmail() + " and id (" +
                currentUser.getUid() + ")");

        // set up the recycler view
        List<ShopSyncModel> shopSyncs = new ArrayList<>();
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewShopSyncs);
        ShopSyncsRecyclerViewAdapter adapter =
                new ShopSyncsRecyclerViewAdapter(this, shopSyncs);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        applicationGraph.shopSyncsService()
                .getShopSyncsWithUserUid(currentUser.getUid())
                .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: task for shop syncs is complete");

                        // gather all the shop syncs into a list
                        DataSnapshot dataSnapshot = task.getResult();
                        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            // Convert each child's value into a ShopSyncModel object
                            ShopSyncModel shopSync = childSnapshot.getValue(ShopSyncModel.class);
                            if (shopSync != null) {
                                shopSyncs.add(shopSync);
                            }
                        }
                        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: retrieved " + shopSyncs.size() + " shop syncs");

                        // notify the adapter that the data set has changed
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {
                        signOutOnErrorAndRedirectToMainActivity("Failed to retrieve shop syncs. " +
                                                                        "Signing out now.");
                    }
                });
    }

}
```

The logs shows that the user uid matches the one in the shop sync user uid list.
[image: logs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Realtime Database can only query for a value in a known path under each direct child node. There is no way to query your `shop_syncs` list for a child node that contains a specific value under its `userUids` property, as the value may be at any index in the array.

---

A better data model would be to store the UIDs as a map, as that eliminates the potential for duplicates. So:

```
userUids: {
  "oH0v0NBQiXSiEiui18UVcF10J1K2": true
}
```

But even with this structure you won't be able to implement the query, as you'd need to name each possible UID in an `.indexOn` clause in your rules.

---

The best way to implement the use-case is to create an additional top-level key, specific for to map from a UID to their shops:

```
shops_by_uid: {
  "oH0v0NBQiXSiEiui18UVcF10J1K2": {
    "shopId1": true,
    "shopId2": true,
    ...
  }
}
```

So with this data structure you can first look up the shop IDs for a given UID, and the look up the individual shops after that.

---

For more on this type of use-case, see [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)

Comment: Thank you very much for that! I'll follow the structure that you recommend and refactor my project accordingly.

Comment: Fyi, I've successfully implemented the structure you recommended. It works! :)